# How i can analysis more than two before- after groups?

Tags: r

I have 3 analysis groups for 200 gene expression, Before analysis(16 samples), one month(16 samples) and two months after analysis(9 samples). How can I analyze these data in R?

This is a schematic of my data.

```
data = matrix(Group = c("AFT-1" , "AFT-2","BEF","AFT-1" , "AFT-2","BEF"),
Sample_code = c(10,10,10,11, 11, 11),
Sex = c("F","F","M","F","M",F),
GENE_a = C(22.88006 , 23.46812,24.23213,24.10917,24.55109),
GENE_b= c(23.24577, 23.08145,23.19317,NaN,NaN),
GENE_c=c(20.00031, 19.57906,20.27364,19.73243,NaN))
```

Comment: I have a problem with the structure of data, to compare between these groups, can I use ANOVA for Before-After analysis?

Answer (score 0):

This type of repeated measures experiment is better addressed using a mixed effect model. To do this in R, I use nlme library to perform this type of analysis.

The authors of that package also wrote the textbook, Pinheiro, J.C., and Bates, D.M. (2000) "Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS", Springer.

The text is thorough in explaining the application of these models to the types of experimental datasets you are describing, and how to interpret the outputs returned by the functions in the package.

Note, The S language is a precursor to R, so the programming syntax used in the book is applicable to R programming.